# SharedWorker loading race condition

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I think I may have a misunderstanding in how shared web workers behave, but I cannot find anything in the spec or MDN (etc) which clarifies.

A test case:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en-gb"><head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Simple Worker Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
window.addEventListener( 'load', function( ) {
    var sharedWorker = new SharedWorker( 'worker.js' );

    sharedWorker.port.addEventListener( 'message', function( e ) {
        console.log( e.data );
    }, false );
    sharedWorker.port.start( );

    sharedWorker.port.postMessage( 'ping' );
    setTimeout( function( ) {
        sharedWorker.port.postMessage( 'pong' );
    }, 2000 );
}, false );
    </script>
</head><body></body></html>
```

worker.js:

```
onconnect = function( e ) {
    var port = e.ports[0];
    port.onmessage = function( e ) {
        port.postMessage( 'echo: ' + e.data );
    };
};
```

When I run that (in Chrome 40) and refresh the page a few times, usually I see "echo: ping" in the console (and later "echo: pong"), but about a third of the time I see neither. It feels like a race condition to me, but I was under the impression that `postMessage` (and port.start) would queue requests until the worker is ready (i.e. loaded and run). I don't see this issue when using non-shared workers.

Update: if I wrap the whole thing in a `setTimeout(...,100)` instead of (or as well as) a load listener, it works every time. If I use 50ms instead of 100, it works *almost* every time. So that's a possible, but *very* unreliable workaround.

Did I miss something? Should I be waiting for an event of some type before setting up the port?

Comment: I've setup a Plunkr to try to recreate your issue http://plnkr.co/edit/n3Cv5JbYGeAgcRnvYSpu?p=preview . On my system (Chrome 38 on Linux), it does look like sometimes neither of the ping/pong messages are shown. I am also not sure why.